# How to 'lock' a cell reference so it doesn't change when sorted/filtered?

Tags: excel-formula

I have a formula that relies on the values in other specific cells to work correctly, yet have found out that when I sort my worksheet randomly these references are replaced with relative references, or absolute ones if I use $ in the cell numbers. I have tried to 'name' the cells but naming them doesn't make a difference. Is there a way to uniquely identify a cell so I can find it no matter if the sheet is sorted or changed?

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of your data?

Answer (score -1):

If I understand correctly, you want the selected range to stay the same regardless of the cell the formula is run from.

This is called absolute cell reference.

To do this, put dollar signs in front of the row or column you want to stay the same. In your example, using COUNTIF($M$100:$M$105) will select the range M100:M105, even when you copy that formula to a different cell.

Comment: No sorry that isn't what I am trying to do. I am trying to select multiple cells individually in a formula rather than a range of them.

Comment: Sorry Beobe, I have changed my question a bit as I have better identified what my problem actually is. Apologies for the muck around.